# Problema com Select e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select

Estou fazendo um form onde a pessoa seleciona o *Item 1*, ao seleciona-lo aparece outro select com as categorias desse item 1. O problema é quando tem mais de 1 item, pois ele está pegando o select da última categoria envés de pegar a categoria selecionada. Já tentei algumas correções mas nenhuma funcionou.

**Esse é o código SELECT:**

```
<?php $procura_cursos = $site->query("SELECT * FROM cursos");
if ($procura_cursos->rowCount() <=0) {

}else{
    while ($curso = $procura_cursos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $procura_tumas = $site->query("SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE curso = '$curso->chns' AND inscricoes ='ativo'");
        if ($procura_tumas->rowCount() <=0) {?>
            <div class="col-md-6 selection tipo<?echo$curso->chns;?>" style="display: none;">
                <label>Sem Horário Disponível para o Curso</label>
            </div>
            <?
        }else{?>
            <div class="col-md-6 selection tipo<?echo$curso->chns;?>" style="display: none;">
                <label for="turma">Escolha os Horários Disponíveis</label>
                <select class="seleciona form-control" name="turma">
                    <option disabled>Selecione o Dia</option>
                    <?while ($turmas = $procura_tumas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo$turmas->chns; ?>"><?php echo $turmas->turma; ?></option>
                        <?
                    }?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <?
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

**Esse é o código SCRIPT:**

```
<?php $procura_cursos = $site->query("SELECT * FROM cursos");
if ($procura_cursos->rowCount() <=0) {

}else{
    while ($curso = $procura_cursos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $procura_tumas = $site->query("SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE curso = '$curso->chns' AND inscricoes ='ativo'");
        if ($procura_tumas->rowCount() <=0) {?>

            <?
        }else{?>
            <script>
                $("select#curso").change(function() {
                    <?while ($turmas = $procura_tumas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                        ?>
                        if ($(this).val() == "<?echo$curso->chns;?>") {
                            $(".tipo<?echo$curso->chns;?>").css("display", "block").fadeIn();
                            <?php 
                            $procura_cursos0 = $site->query("SELECT * FROM cursos where chns != '$curso->chns'");
                            if ($procura_cursos0->rowCount() <=0) {

                            }else{
                                while ($curso0 = $procura_cursos0->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                                    $procura_tumas0 = $site->query("SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE curso != '$curso0->chns' AND inscricoes ='ativo'");
                                    if ($procura_tumas0->rowCount() <=0) {

                                    }else{
                                        while ($turmas0 = $procura_tumas0->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {?>
                                            $(".tipo<?echo$curso0->chns;?>").css("display", "none").fadeOut();
                                            <?  
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        }
                        <?
                    }?>
                });
            </script>
            <?
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No onchange tu tem que pegar o id que foi selecionado.

var id = $('#id_do_select').val();

e a partir daí tu vai tratando conforme o id que foi selecionado.